# On the formation of Earth's moon

Tags: gravity, earth, geophysics, moon

NASA states that :

> The moon was formed ~4.5 billion years ago, about 30–50 million years
>   after the origin of the Solar System, out of debris thrown into orbit
>   by a massive collision between a smaller proto-Earth and another
>   planetoid, about the size of Mars.

If we consider the gravity anomaly map of the world (from GOCE data) we observe a low at some places ( Indian Ocean , Canada , .. ) 
[image]

Is it possible that this is where the Moon was gouged out of the Earth long ago and it still hasn't recovered completely or is there some better explanation to for these gravity anomalies.

Comment: There were probably a lot of collisions over time that probably mask the big one. Like the iceland meteor, for example. Also, most of the effect of a really big collision would be within the mantle, where it would get quickly dissipated because of flow.